# Prove propositional formula is a tautology

Tags: logic

I need to show this formula is a theorem of propositional calculus. I tried assuming antecedent and proving consequent but didn't work for this proof. Do I need to show it is equivalent to true? How should I start? It's not possible to use truth tables.

$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \wedge r \rightarrow q \wedge r)$

Background:

In my class, there is no mention to it but I think this form of logic it's called Equational Logic.
Probably, it's based on this book: A Logical Approach to Discrete Math
by David Gries

EDIT:
I was asked to provide more details on the type of proof needed. In my class, I am not allowed to use truth tables to prove this proposition. This is an example:

[image]

Comment: "It's not possible to use truth tables." Do you mean it is not *allowed* for you to do so?

Comment: A "theorem" is a "tautology", but the converse is not necessarily true. A theorem has to be proven from a set of axioms and deduction rules. Review these and I'm sure you'll figure out how to do it. Come back and edit your question with your attempts at a solution once you've done so.

Comment: The question is impossible to answer unless you tell us what constitutes a proof in your case.

Comment: @dkaeae I’ll clarify. I’m not allowed to use truth tables. Later, I will edit the question and add details to make it more specific. Thanks to all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the formula states:

> If $p$ implies $q$, then $p$ and $r$ imply $q$ and $r$.

To prove this, you would like to argue as follows. Assume $p$ implies $q$, and suppose that both $p$ and $r$ hold. Since $p$ implies $q$, then $q$ holds. Hence both $q$ and $r$ hold.

How exactly this proof is expressed depends on your proof system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the more general theorem

$((a \rightarrow b) \land (c \rightarrow d)) \rightarrow ((a \land c) \rightarrow (b \land d)$

You may find it easier to prove the general theorem first, then prove the special case by setting $a=p, \space b=q, \space c=d=r$.